# Some packages contain repeated meta data

Tags: apt-cache, duplicate-files

For example, `libelf1` has duplicate package meta data, i.e.

```
$ apt-cache show libelf1 | grep 'Architecture:'
Architecture: amd64
Architecture: amd64
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not duplicate,they are different files(may be different versions) in same package.

If you run `apt-cache show libelf1` you will get,

Package: libelf1

Filename: pool/main/e/elfutils/libelf1_0.158-0ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb
Size: 37966

Filename: pool/main/e/elfutils/libelf1_0.158-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
Size: 38320

Please refer [launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libelf1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libelf1)

Comment: Just wondering if there are any options on `apt-cache show` for filtering the results to only the latest version?